# Map Markers only Load After Clearing of Browser Cache

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website at www.procomport.com only works in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Every time I post a question with all my code everyone keeps yelling saying they need code to be posted what else do you want from me!? The JS works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox but nothing else.

Javascript

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var lat1;
var lng1;
var lat2;
var lng2;
var range;
var htmlcard;
var initialLocation;
var measure;


function initialize() {



    var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0522, -118.2428);
    var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
    var browserSupportFlag = new Boolean();


    var address = document.getElementById("addressForm");
    //alert(address.value.trim().length);


    //alert(address.value.length);
    if (address.value.length <= 2) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                //createMap2(initialLocation);

                load(initialLocation);

                lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
                lng1 = position.coords.longitude;

            }, function () {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
        }
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag == true) {
                //alert("Failed to find location.");
                //createMap(newyork);
                load(newyork);

            } else {
                //alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in Los Angeles.");
                //createMap(siberia);
                load(siberia);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById("addressForm").value;

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                load(results[0].geometry.location)

                lat1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            }
        });

    }


}

function load(center) {

     range = document.getElementById("distance").value;

    if (range == "" || range == 0)
        {
            range = "200";
        }
    measure = document.getElementById("measure").value;

    if (measure !== "m") {
        measure == "km";
    }

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions1 = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions1);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: center
    });

    var professionFilter = document.getElementById("professionFilterValue").value;

    //alert(professionFilter);

    downloadUrl("xml.php?p=" + professionFilter, function (data) {

        var xml = data.responseXML; // xml file generated from xml.php

        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); // parses XML and gets Markers From Data


        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {


            // Sets infoWindow for specific marker 
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxwidth: 350 });

             google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () { infoWindow.close(); });

            //========================================================================================= 
            // Sets Marker Attributes an Location

            lat2 = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
            lng2 = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");

            var distance = getDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
            var display_name = markers[i].getAttribute('dname')

            var card = markers[i].getAttribute('card')
            var htmlCard = decodeURIComponent(card)

            if (getDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) < range) {

                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var html = htmlCard
                var icon = "https://www.procomport.com/site/www/images/computericon.png"
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: "/site/www/images/computericon.png",
                    shadow: icon.shadow,
                    title: name
                });

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        }

        //=========================================================================================
    });
}
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        setTimeout(function () { infoWindow.setContent(html); }, '1000');
        setTimeout(function () { infoWindow.open(map, marker); }, '1000');
        setTimeout(function () { infoWindow.close(); }, '5000');

    });

}
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}
function doNothing() { }

function getDistance(lat11, lon11, lat22, lon22) {
    var R;

    if (measure == "km") {
        R = 6371;
    }
    else {
        R = 3959;
    }
    // km (change this constant to get miles)
    var dLat = (lat22 - lat11) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon22 - lon11) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    if (d > 1) return Math.round(d);
    else if (d <= 1) return Math.round(d * 1000);

    return d;

}
```

Like I am really losing my mind what am I doing wrong I ran the W3 validator as I was told and fixed a lot of errors (except the meta tags) 
[Validator Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://www.procomport.com/map.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1)

What other code is needed to accurately diagnose this problem?

Internet Explorer Console output.

```
HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (META tag) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (META tag) 
map.php
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document. 
map.php, line 154 character 1
HTML1522: Invalid end tag: "</br>". Use "<br>" or "<br/>" instead. 
map.php, line 322 character 9
HTML1522: Invalid end tag: "</br>". Use "<br>" or "<br/>" instead. 
map.php, line 524 character 164
HTML1522: Invalid end tag: "</br>". Use "<br>" or "<br/>" instead. 
map.php, line 524 character 343
HTML1522: Invalid end tag: "</br>". Use "<br>" or "<br/>" instead. 
map.php, line 525 character 120
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
```

UPDATE:

Fixed all IE Errors - Still No Markers

UPDATE 2:

Made some progress every time I clear the browser cache and reload the page it works fine.

Update 3:

The map doesn't even load on Safari

Comment: Asking the same question 3 times isn't going to get you an answer faster.

Comment: 1) create the smallest "complete page" (html, css, javascript, php...) that you need to recreate "the problem"; 2) describe the problem that you are observing, and how different platforms behave differently. Does it fail in "any Explorer browser"; how about Safari? Does it depend on version, proxy settings, operating system... 3) Tell us where you think the problem might be.

Comment: You are posting javascript. The `procomport.com` page redirects to a `.php` . Is there anything else we need to see? When I look at the page source, it's 726 lines long. Start trimming the source - if the problem goes away, you will have a clue; and if it remains, you will have narrowed it down. Finally, describe what "not working" means.

Comment: @Floris the map markers won't load on page load. If I set static points it won't help because your location won't automatically center where points on the map are that's why I keep trying to post the url. If you manually put a location on the map the page loads fine.

Comment: @Wooble I keep posting the question because every time I keep getting people telling me that I don't have enough information. So each time I add more information until I can get some progress. I'm not doing this to be annoying I just legitimately don't know what you guys want me to do.

Comment: @RichardParker can you create a simple program that displays your problem - no php, no 700 lines of code. Standalone code that I could paste into Notepad, then open from any browser to observe the problem. That's how you will get help. Also - you can edit a question, you don't have to keep posting a new one. It has the advantage of letting people see other comments etc - then one doesn't have to go looking at other questions you may have posted. And I believe that every time you edit your question it "bubbles back to the top" on the new questions list, so it keeps getting new viewers.

Comment: @Floris thank you for that I thought it was like a forum and it goes back to the bottom after it doesn't receive comments after a while. But with that said all the map points are static points. So if you load the map if you don't live in Los Angeles (or the other places where there are markers) you wouldn't see anything anyway. That's why it's extremely difficult for me to figure out how to keep the code the same as it is while providing a good example.

Comment: You could zoom out to "the whole world", then it doesn't matter where I live. You are after the location markers, not the map detail, after all. And the goal is not "keep the code the same", but "demonstrate the problem with a small, self-contained piece of code". Very different task. In the process of creating it you may discover your problem yourself.

Comment: Post the console output from the browsers that fail. Posting your entire code doesnt help. I certainly wont waste time trying to debug so much code. Post a minimal sample that doesnt work.

Comment: @ZigMandel I have posted the Internet Explorer Console Output I don't know how to get to a console in Safari

Comment: Well you have it right there. There are a ton of html syntax errors that IE is complaining about in particular multiple body tags and many unclosed tags. Fix them all and try again.

Comment: @ZigMandel I fixed all the errors except one coming from a facebook widget. Still the markers won't load on the map. I'm working on a standalone version.